# Getting Unknown host URL exception for Corda Doorman

Tags: corda

I am planning to generate a certificate and register the identity of the node in Corda network. I have used this URL `http://testnet.certificate.corda.net` but it throws an exception if I trigger the command (`java -jar corda.jar`) with `--initial-registration`.

This is the stack trace:

```
Submitting certificate signing request to Corda certificate signing server.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: cordaci-netperm.corda.
r3cev.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewH
ttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Sou
rce)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Sour
ce)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect
(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown
Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown S
ource)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unk
nown Source)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.registration.HTTPNetworkRegistrationService.
submitRequest(HTTPNetworkRegistrationService.kt:51)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.registration.NetworkRegistrationHelper.submi
tOrResumeCertificateSigningRequest(NetworkRegistrationHelper.kt:142)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.registration.NetworkRegistrationHelper.build
Keystore(NetworkRegistrationHelper.kt:61)
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.maybeRegisterWithNetworkAndExit(N
odeStartup.kt:148)
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.run(NodeStartup.kt:69)
    at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following the instructions here instead: https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html#starting-the-registration.